# Reloading directory-local variables

Tags: directory-local-variables

How do you reload  directory-local variables?  I would like to modify a `.dir-locals.el` and have such changes applied to the current Emacs session.

Comment: The directory-local variables don't apply to the session - they apply to every buffer related to a file in that directory. So, one approach, if you are fine with reverting your open buffers, would be to simply revert all of them, by running through `buffer-list`.

Comment: @Pradhan: Albeit I would rather employ a more direct approach, your suggestion worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Pradhan I was wrong: reverting the buffer does not work, unless the local variables have been registered as safe.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This function will re-read the dir-locals file and set the new values for the current buffer:

```lisp
(defun my-reload-dir-locals-for-current-buffer ()
  "reload dir locals for the current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let ((enable-local-variables :all))
    (hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer)))
```

And if you want to reload dir-locals for every buffer in your current buffer's directory:

```lisp
(defun my-reload-dir-locals-for-all-buffer-in-this-directory ()
  "For every buffer with the same `default-directory` as the 
current buffer's, reload dir-locals."
  (interactive)
  (let ((dir default-directory))
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (when (equal default-directory dir)
          (my-reload-dir-locals-for-current-buffer))))))
```

You could have all the dir locals refresh every time you save a dir-locals file by adding an `after-save-hook` to .dir-locals.el buffers.

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          (defun enable-autoreload-for-dir-locals ()
            (when (and (buffer-file-name)
                       (equal dir-locals-file
                              (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))))
              (add-hook 'after-save-hook
                        'my-reload-dir-locals-for-all-buffer-in-this-directory
                        nil t))))
```

Of course this could have unintended consequences because it will reset the variables values regardless of whether they have been changed elsewhere, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I _almost_ feel like this should be built into Emacs.

Comment: alternatively, one can add a warning asking for confirmation in the autoreload function if some variable will be erase.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use: `M-: (hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer)`

---

**To check it works**: from a buffer (an org mode file for instance), type `M-x add-dir-local-variable`, then validate (default org-mode), then type demo RET, then "this is a demo" RET.

Your *.dir-locals.el* file will appear in a buffer:

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((org-mode
  (demo . "this is a demo")))
```

You have to save it: `C-x C-s`

Then go back to your org mode buffer and check that the demo variable is not defined (`C-h C-v demo`)

Here you can use the trick: `M-: (hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer)`

Now `C-h C-v demo` will print:

> demo’s value is "this is a demo" Local in buffer poub.org; globally
>   void
>
> This variable’s value is directory-local, set by the file
>   ‘/home/picaud/Temp/.dir-locals.el’.
>
> Documentation: Not documented as a variable.